# Trigger delegate method on ng-click? - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, eventtrigger

I'm trying to trigger delegate method on ng-click.

Here's my code.

I've a button with a function hi passing an ID to it.

```
<input type="button" value="button" ng-click="hi(item.runId)"/>
```

In the JS file I've the below.

```
$scope.hi = function(id){
            alert(id);
            //Trigger the delegate method here
        };

        $(document).delegate('input[type="button"]','click',function(){
            {
                $('[colspan="5"]').parent('tr').remove();
                $(this).parents('tr').after('<tr/>').next().append('<td colspan="5"/>').children('td').append('<div/>').children().html($('#divSlide').html());
            }

        });
```

I'm trying to append a row dynamically on the button click, at the same time I'm trying to pass an ID with which the generated row would be dependent on.

What is happening now is that on click of the button both the methods are called simultaneously, with the given code ideally that should be happening.

But I'm trying to trigger the delegate event only from the hi function not on button click.

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Advice: remove jquery and try to do it properly with only Angular. It will teach you right Angular approach of coding. Avoid using jQuery in general, until you understand how to do it without it.

Comment: Can't you just put the code inside the `hi` function?

Comment: Angular emphasizes a strong separation of concerns. In your code example you are mixing business logic (that belongs in your controller) and DOM manipulation (that belongs into a directive). Common sense is that DOM manipulation should be done in directives. The official documentation should get you started.

Comment: Use `ng-repeat` and push data to array to do what you are doing .... or don't bother using angular if you aren't going to use it properly